# Why jmeter average response time is high compared to load runner for the same test

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter average response time is high compared to the load runner for the same test scenario , response time gradually increases for some samplers.

I am using multiple thread groups for different test scenarios.
all scenarios are executing successfully but average response time is not accurate(40 secs in Jmeter, 8 secs in load runner and manual execution)

how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the heap size that you have configured for JMeter? Are you using standard samplers, assertions, pre/post processors without any custom coding in beanshell or JSR223?

Comment: Heap size is 1GB, HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g , i am using all standard samplers,assertions,pre/post processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you get all embedded resources in JMeter scenario and does not get them in Load Runner. Could you check this settings?

Comment: i did not check this setting in HTTP request default, i tried with both check and uncheck this setting.. no difference coming in the response. Can you please suggest

Comment: This setting can be unchecked in HTTP Request Defaults, but can be checked in each Requests, check them also.

Comment: And do you have any timers in your plan?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions,i dont have any timers yet in the test plan, i tried checking embedded resouce settings, dont see any change,still the same jmeter response time